# Solve for differential equation $dy/dx=dx/dy$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My approach is:

$$\int\int dydy=\int\int dxdx$$

$$(y+a)^2=(x+b)^2$$

$$y=\pm x+c$$

I am not sure if I made mistakes, though, especially the first and second steps. Could you please check it? Any answers will be appreciated.

---

Are there anything wrong with:
$$\int\int dydy=\int\int dxdx$$
$$\int(y+c_1)dy=\int(x+c_2)dx$$

$$(y+a)^2=(x+b)^2+c\ \  ???$$
This seems inconsistent with the correct  answer.

Comment: Compute $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+b}{y+a}$. This does not equal $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y+a}{x+b}$.

Comment: The way you fix this discrepancy is to recognize that by using indefinite integrals as a way of solving differential equations you are introducing additional degrees of freedom (i.e. constants of integration) which must be constrained by the original equation. Thus, in the answer above, $c$ is an additional degree of freedom, and the solution only holds if $c =0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your result is correct.

Another approach :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dy}\quad\to\quad \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2=1\quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\pm 1 \quad\to\quad y=\pm x+c$$

Comment: Are there anything wrong with:
$\int\int dydy=\int\int dxdx \  \ \ $
$\to  \ \ \ \ \ \  \int(y+c_1)dy=\int(x+c_2)dx \  \ \ \ $

$\to \  \   (y+a)^2=(x+b)^2+c\ \  ???$

Comment: $\int (y+c_1)dy=\int(x+c_2)dx \quad\to\quad y^2+2c_1y+c_3=x^2+2c_2x+c_5 \quad\to\quad  (y+c_1)^2+c_5=(x+c_2)^2+c_6 \quad\to\quad (y+a)^2=(x+b)^2+c$

Comment: It seems like contradicting our previous answers. $y=\pm\sqrt{(x+b)^2+c}-a\neq\pm x+c$

Comment: The integrations introduces supernumerary solutions which have to be rejected. One have to bring back the whole into the initial ODE and check what are the convenient solutions. Finally, with $c=0$ the correct result is obtained. Note that High GPA didn't edit all steps. So it was not possible to check what was done exactly. That is why, in my answer, I wrote "Your result is correct". But I didn't write "Your calculus is correct".

Answer (score 5):

Your approach, even though it leads to the correct result, is **black magic** to me. It is true that for ODEs of the type$$y'=f(x)g(y)$$
we use the method of separating variables:
$$\int_{y_0}^y{1\over g(y')}\>dy'=\int_{x_0}^x f(x')\>dx'\ ,$$
because  long ago we have seen the (not so simple) proof that this is o.k. On the other hand, I don't know what $\int\int dy\>dy$ means (shouldn't there be two constants of integration in the end?), nor do I have the slightest trust that your playing with the symbols (even if meaningful) will lead to a correct result.

Your differential equation is saying no more and no less than $y'={1\over y'}$, and then should be solved along the lines of JJacquelin's answer.

Comment: You are right. It was black magic which I did not trust. The recently added approach includes two constants, which seems not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just for curiosity :

In order to avoid supernumerary solutions, one have to use definite integrals instead of indefinite. It becomes more complicated : 
$$\int_{y_2=-a}^{y_2=y}\left(\int_{y_1=-a}^{y_1=y_2}dy_1 \right)dy_2 = \int_{x_2=-b}^{x_2=x}\left(\int_{x_1=-b}^{x_1=x_2}dx_1 \right)dx_2$$
with arbitrary $a$ and $b$.

Note : For the term at left be equal to the term at right, the starting point for integration must be the same on both sides, say $(-a,-b)$. These notation is chosen to be consistent with the notation of the previous answers. This explains why the lower bounds are common for each double integral.

$$\int_{y_2=-a}^{y_2=y}\left(y_2+a \right)dy_2 = \int_{x_2=-b}^{x_2=x}\left(x_2+b \right)dx_2$$

$$\left[\frac{y_2^2}{2}+ay_2+c_1\right]_{y_2=-a}^{y_2=y} = \left[\frac{x_2^2}{2}+bx_2+c_2\right]_{x_2=-b}^{x_2=x}$$

$$\left(\frac{y^2}{2}+ay+c_1\right)-\left(\frac{(-a)^2}{2}+a(-a)+c_1\right) = \left(\frac{x^2}{2}+bx+c_2\right)-\left(\frac{(-b)^2}{2}+b(-b)+c_2\right)$$

$$\frac{y^2}{2}+ay+\frac{a^2}{2} =\frac{x^2}{2}+bx+\frac{b^2}{2}$$
$$(y+a)^2=(x+b)^2$$
$$y+a=\pm(x+b) \quad\to\quad y=\pm x+c$$

Obviously this method is not recommended compared to the method with $y'^2=1$.

Comment: May I ask why the starting point of integration $y_1$ must equal $y_2=-a$?

Comment: The starting point can be any value that you want. $-a$ , for example. But it could be $A$. If $A$ is chosen, at the end we have $(y-A)^2$. Since $(y+a)^2$ was used in the previous answers, let $A=-a$ to be consistent with the previous symbol. Also It is explain in the "Note" written in the main answer why the starting point of integration $y_1$ must be equal to $y_2$, say $=A$ and the starting point of integration $x_1$ must be equal to $x_2$, say $=B$ for a common starting point $(A,B)$. If the stating pont wasn't common the two double-integrals wouldn't be not equal.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dy}\implies\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int\frac{dx}{dy}dx=\frac{d}{dy}\int x dx$$
Thus,
$$\int \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx dy = \int\frac{d}{dy}\int x dx dy$$
Looking at the l.h.s.,
$$\int \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx dy=\int (y + a) dy=\frac{(y+a)^2}{2}+c_1$$
On the r.h.s.,
$$\int\frac{d}{dy}\int x dx dy= \int\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+c_2\right)dy=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_2$$
Thus,
$$\frac{(y+a)^2}{2}+c_1=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_2$$
Or,
$$(y+a)^2=x^2+b$$

Now, recognize that 
$$\frac{d}{dy}(y+a)^2 = 2x \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y+a}$$
Similarly,
$$2(y+a)=2x\frac{dx}{dy}\implies\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y+a}{x}$$

In order to satisfy the original equation, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dy}$ we conclude that $b=0$. Thus, 
$$(y+a)^2 = x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dy}=k \Rightarrow \begin{cases} dy=kdx \\ \frac{dx}{k}=dy \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} y=kx+C \\ y=\frac{1}{k}x+C\end{cases} \Rightarrow k=\frac{1}{k} \Rightarrow k=\pm 1 \Rightarrow y=\pm x+C.$$